# How to embed spark dataframe columns to a map column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark dataframe with many many columns. Now, I want to combine them together to a map and build a new column.
e.g.

```
col1:String col2:String col3:String... coln:String =>
col: Map(colname -> colval)
```

One way to do this is to:

```
df.withColumn("newcol", struct(df.columns.head, df.columns.tail: _*))
```

However, I still have to convert df to `dataset`. I have no idea how to define the case class that can match `struct` type here.

Another option is to embed columns to Map type, but I do not know how to express this.

Comment: how many rows do you have in your dataframe?

Comment: around 40, and it is quite tedious to list them one by one

Comment: I don't understand the question. `Map(colname -> colval)` Should `colval` be an array of all values under `colname` ? And the way that you have provided will get each row as struct. Not exactly similar to what you have explained above. Can you please elaborate with a sample dataset and required output.

Comment: I don't understand the question neither. An MVCE is in need here.

Comment: Please include a sample dataframe and expected dataframe.

Answer (score 7):

For performance reasons, you can avoid rolling your own UDF by using the **existing** Spark function:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map
```

Here is a fully worked example:

```
var mydata = Seq(("a", "b", "c"), ("d", "e", "f"), ("g", "h", "i"))
                 .toDF("f1", "f2", "f3")

var colnms_n_vals = mydata.columns.flatMap { c => Array(lit(c), col(c)) }

display(mydata.withColumn("myMap", map(colnms_n_vals:_*)))
```

Results in this:

```
f1  f2  f3  myMap
a   b   c   {"f1":"a","f2":"b","f3":"c"}
d   e   f   {"f1":"d","f2":"e","f3":"f"}
g   h   i   {"f1":"g","f2":"h","f3":"i"}
```

Comment: Worth noting that all columns need to have the same datatype for this to work (as per Spark API documentation)

Comment: One way to avoid the issues with data types is to change the expression to var colnms_n_vals = mydata.columns.flatMap { c => Array(lit(c), col(c).cast("String")) }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build new column from all existing columns, here is one simple solution.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val columnsName = ds.columns
val mkMap = udf((values: mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => columnsName.zip(values).toMap)
ds.withColumn("new_col", mkMap(array(columnsName.head, columnsName.tail:_*)))
```